# Response from POST /sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send API

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

We are calling the following API to invoke messages from Marketing Cloud Mobile Connect. We are getting a token Id in response, I wanted to know in which API can I use this token Id.

POST /sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your situation, the API returns a token ID that can be used to make a follow-up call to check the status of the request.

There are two types API requests that can be made using that token ID:

- **[Get Message Contact Status](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getMessageContactDelivery.htm)**

  > GET /sms/v1/messageContact/{messageId}/deliveries/{tokenId}
- **[Get Message Contact History](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getMessageContactHistory.htm)**

  > GET
  >   /sms/v1/messageContact/{messageId}/history/{tokenId}/mobileNumber/{mobileNumber}

Also, please check the errors from the response **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageList.htm)** for the message contact status and history.